AWS Bedrock Input.text 1000 character limitation using a knowledge base?
Me and a team of mine have been trying to incorporate AWS' Bedrock into our project a while. We recently have given it a knowledge base, but have seen the input for a query to said knowledge base is only 1000 characters long which is.. limiting.
Has anyone found a way around this? For example: storing the user prompt externally, transferring to S3, and giving that to the model? I also read through some billing documentation that mentions going through 1000 characters as a limit for one input.text, before it automatically goes through to the next. I'm assuming this means the json can be configured to have multiple input.text objects?
I'd appreciate any help! ^-^
I've tried messing around with the json file directly send in request, but haven't found an actual way to bypass this limitation. Even in the knowledge base default window, the 1000 character limit exists.

I ended up checking if the input was over 1000 chars. If yes, then first send the input to a llm with the prompt, "Summarize this text to max 600 characters. The text will be used to retrieve documents from a vector storage" (adjust as needed).
Then use the returned text to fetch context with the original input to generate the answer.
